# Primes is in P, proof of hendrik Lenstra Jr. lemma

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, finite-fields, cyclotomic-polynomials, primality-test

In the paper describing AKS primality test : http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v160-n2-p12.pdf

On page no. 8 Lemma 4.7 last paragraph, I cannot understand how number of distinct polynomials with degree less than $t$ is calculated.

I understood that number of distinct polynomials with degree equal to 1 is $l + 1$, but how is the formula for a general degree ($t$) is derived?
Can anyone please help me with this.

Although this paper also describes an induction method to prove this on page no. 8, but I could not understand how the number of polynomials with degree $(t - 1)$ is calculated here.Link: http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/jpaulson/AKS.pdf

Comment: Please post the relevant mathematical details here, and leave the link as reference for extended information.

Comment: I have written my doubt clearly. Can you please say what mathematical details are you asking for.

Comment: Any detail which is available at the given link but not within this post, AND - which is required (IYO) for answering this question.

Comment: this is better written: http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/Bulletin04.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have understood the solution. The solution can be produced by using integral equation :
e0 + e1+ e2+ ....+ el = t.

Comment: This post has been flagged. I first converted it to a comment, but I'm having second thoughts. I'm glad that you figured out the answer to your question. But for the benefit of future readers you should give more details before you wrap up this question by accepting your own answer.