# In Lemma 4.7 of AKS, why do distinct polynomials map to distinct elements modulo h(x)?

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials, primality-test

I am reading [Primes is in P](https://doi.org/10.4007/annals.2004.160.781) by Agrawal, Kayal and Saxena, and I can't understand part of the proof of Lemma 4.7 (already the subject of two questions here: [PRIMES in P paper - Lemma 4.7 - why are the polynomials $X^m$ distinct in $F$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3051604/59435) and [Primes is in P, proof of hendrik Lenstra Jr. lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1832072/59435)).

Let $\DeclareMathOperator{\ord}{ord}\ord_r(p)$ mean the order of $p$ modulo $r$, i.e. the least $k$ such that $p^k \equiv 1 \pmod r$.

We have $p$ a prime and $r$ an integer, $p > r$,
and a polynomial $h(x)$ which is an irreducible factor of the $r$th cyclotomic polynomial $Q_r(x)$ over the finite field $F_p$; the degree of $h(x)$ is $\ord_r(p)$.

Some other numbers involved are $n$, $t$, and $\ell$; I'd hope you don't need to worry about their details. But in case you do, $n$ is a multiple of $p$ with $\ord_r(n) > \log(n)^2$, where $\log$ is the binary log;
$\ell = \lfloor{\sqrt{\phi(r)}\log(n)}\rfloor$, where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function;
and $t$ is the number of elements of $I := \{ (\frac{n}{p})^i p^j \mid i,j \geq 0\}$ which are distinct modulo $r$; these $t$ residues form a group $G$.

Let $P$ be the set of all polynomials of the form $\prod_{a=0}^\ell (x + a)^{e_a}$, with powers $e_a \geq 0$.
The statement I am confused about says that any two distinct polynomials in $P$ of degree less than $t$ map to different elements in the field $F := F_p[x]/(h(x))$.

I'll reproduce the beginning of the proof. "$m$ is introspective for $f$" means $f(x)^m = f(x^m) \pmod{x^r-1,p}$.

> First note that since $h(x)$ is a factor of the cyclotomic polynomial
>   $Q_r(x)$, $x$ is a primitive $r$th root of unity in $F$.
>
> We now show that any two distinct polynomials of degree less than $t$
>   in $P$ will map to different elements in F. Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two such
>   polynomials in $P$. Suppose $f(x) = g(x)$ in the field $F$. Let $m \in I$. We also
>   have $f(x)^m = g(x)^m$ in $F$. Since $m$ is introspective for both $f$ and $g$, and
>   $h(x)$ divides $x^r − 1$, we get:
>   \[
>   f(x^m) = g(x^m)
>   \]
>   in $F$. This implies that $x^m$ is a root of the polynomial $Q(Y) = f(Y) − g(Y)$
>   for every $m \in G$. Since $(m, r)=1$ ($G$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_r^*$), each such $x^m$ is a primitive $r$th root of unity. Hence there will be $|G| = t$ distinct roots of $Q(Y)$
>   in $F$. However, the degree of $Q(Y)$ is less than $t$ by the choice of $f$ and $g$. This
>   is a contradiction and therefore, $f(x) \neq g(x)$ in $F$.

But, isn't $Q(Y)$ just identically zero, since $f(x) = g(x)$, so $f(Y) = g(Y)$?

Comment: easier to read and complete: https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2005-42-01/S0273-0979-04-01037-7/S0273-0979-04-01037-7.pdf

Comment: "Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two **such** polynomials" must refer to the previous sentence's mention of "**distinct** polynomials**", so it's not the case that $f(x)=g(x)$. Note that $Q(Y)=f(Y)-g(Y)$ is being defined as a polynomial with coefficients in $\Bbb Z$, not in $F$, so this is not contracted by the sentence "Suppose $f(x)=g(x)$ in the field $F$."

Comment: @GregMartin: But if we only know $f(x^m) = g(x^m)$ in $F$, then doesn't that only imply that $Q$ has at least $t$ roots in $F$, which is hardly surprising since I'd expect it to be zero (in $F$)?

Comment: Yes, I think "at least $t$ roots of $Q(Y)$ in $F$" is accurate. But that only helps the reaching of the contradiction in the last few lines.

Comment: @WillJagy: Thanks for the recommendation. It took me a couple of days but I read to the part that covers this issue, and I think it cleared it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading through the paper suggested by Will Jagy in the comments, [It is easy to determine whether a given integer is prime](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2005-42-01/S0273-0979-04-01037-7/S0273-0979-04-01037-7.pdf) by Andrew Granville, seems to have clarified this.

This part of AKS Lemma 4.7 is addressed in Granville's Lemma 4.3 on page 19, which tackles the contrapositive statement:
If $f(x) \equiv g(x) \mod (p, h(x))$, where $f$ and $g$ in $P$ have degree less than $t$, then $f(x) \equiv g(x) \mod p$.

The difference of the two polynomials is now called $\Delta(y)$, and I take it that it's understood to live in $\mathbb{F}[y]$.
I think the part I was missing is the reinterpretation of $f$ and $g$ here: 
Rather than a sum of coefficients times powers of $x$ the element of $\mathbb{F}$
(an $r$th root of unity),
we are going back to the polynomials with integer coefficients, which we can
evaluate at arbitrary elements of $F$.

When evaluated at the $t$ elements of $\mathbb{F}$ of the form $x^k$ for $k \in G$, $\Delta(x^k)$ is zero, so $\Delta$ must be the zero polynomial modulo $(p, h(x))$.

Then it says "which implies that $\Delta(y) \equiv 0 \pmod p$ since its coefficients are independent of $x$"—that is, because all its coefficients are integers.

[As a side note, I really wish people would stop saying "$f(x)$" when they just mean the polynomial $f$ itself, not an example of its output. That alone would help to make this situation clearer.]